# Where does onChange pass arguments to its handelers

Tags: reactjs, components, onchange

With the below code

```
<div className="input-first-line-right">
  <Input
  type="textarea"
  label="Project Description"
  onChange={this.handleDescChange}
  value={this.state.projectDescription}
  />
</div>
```

```
  handleDescChange = text => {
    if (!text) return;
    this.setState({ projectDescription: text });
  };
```

If handleDescChange is expecting an argument 'text' how come it is never passed.
Meaning why isn't the code

```
onChange={this.handleDescChange("some new text")}
```

inorder for the function to work. How does the code inherintly know what the parameter is if nothing is ever passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

For `onChange` attribute, `this.handleDescChange` isn't called here. 
Here, `this.handleDescChange` is given as callback. Input component calls `this.handleDescChange` when the change event is triggered.

If you want to pass a variable you can use fat arrow function. Solution is given below.

```
<div className="input-first-line-right">
  <Input
  type="textarea"
  label="Project Description"
  onChange={event => this.handleDescChange(event.target.value)}
  value={this.state.projectDescription}
  />
</div>
```

```
handleDescChange = text => {
    if (!text) return;
    this.setState({ projectDescription: text });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

> This warning is triggered when we try to access to a React synthetic event in an asynchronous way. Because of the **reuse**, after the event callback has been invoked the synthetic event object will **no longer exist** so we cannot access its properties. [source](https://medium.com/trabe/react-syntheticevent-reuse-889cd52981b6)

The source link above have the correct answer but here is the summary:

1. Use **event.persist()**

> Note: If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call **event.persist()** on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code. [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      projectDescription: ""
    };
  }

  handleDescChange = event => {
    // Add here
    event.persist();
    // Don't check for '!text' Check if there is a value 
    if (event.target.value === 0) return;
    this.setState({ projectDescription: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="input-first-line-right">
        <input
          type="textarea"
          label="Project Description"
          onChange={this.handleDescChange}
          value={this.state.projectDescription}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Though, I would recommend to start learning/use React [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) as it is more clean, elegant way to do this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  // useState hook
  const [projectDescription, setProjectDescription] = useState("");

  const handleDescChange = event => {
    if (event.target.value === 0) return;
    setProjectDescription(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="input-first-line-right">
      <input
        type="textarea"
        label="Project Description"
        onChange={handleDescChange}
        value={projectDescription}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```